# How to handle the consumable in app purchase refunds?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am have consumable in app purchase in my application. User will get credits for each time purchases.

Now incase if user ask Apple to refund I want to decrease that in app credit for that user too.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't do anything with a refund; you simply have to take the loss and move on.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to revoke access to content if they have been refunded. I believe this is by design.

It is possible to get the refund for the in-app purchase by using the following steps in the [link](http://www.imore.com/how-to-get-refund-itunes-app-store).